# Why does my div shift in Opera when toggling hidden div?

Tags: jquery, css, html, opera

This works fine in all the other browsers but for some reason when I run it in Opera the whole app_cont div seems to shunt a few pixels to the left when I click btn1. I think it has something to do with the icon_div because it doesn't shunt over when I remove it. The icon div is actually svg image but I've changed it to a div because I don't know how to upload th e file onto SO. I'd reall appreciate it if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
body{line-height:1}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}
nav ul{list-style:none}
blockquote,q{quotes:none}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}
a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
ins{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;text-decoration:none}
mark{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}
del{text-decoration:line-through}
abbr[title],dfn[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}
input,select{vertical-align:middle}


#app_cont {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    background: #efefef;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px
}

#ab_cont {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 0px 0;
}




#answerBox {
    margin: 0px 10px 15px 0px;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    height: auto;
    width: 225px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: left;
}

#prog_bar {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

#prog_inner {
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #3299bb;
    width: 15%;
}

#btn_cont {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #dcdcdc;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#btn1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#btn3 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#sub_btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #545454;
    border: 1px solid #545454;
    height: 27px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 27px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    float: left;
}

.app_btns {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #ededed),
        color-stop(100%, #dfdfdf) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    filter: progid :                                 
                   DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (             


                            startColorstr =                      
                              '#ededed', endColorstr =     

                 '#dfdfdf' );
    background-color: #ededed;
    color: #777777;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.app_btns:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #dfdfdf),
        color-stop(100%, #ededed) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    filter: progid :                                 
                   DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (             


                            startColorstr =                      
                              '#dfdfdf', endColorstr =     

                 '#ededed' );
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.app_btns:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

#hid_div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #f1e8ba;
    width: 482px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #313131;
}

#icon_div {
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px -12px 20px;
    background:darkgrey;
}

#icon {
    float: left;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin: -8px 0px 0px 20px;
    background:black;
}

#link {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    /*  float: right;*/ /*  margin: -10px 0px 10px 0px;*/
    margin: -16px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#ff9900;
}



</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app_cont">


        <div id="game_pnl">

            <div id="prog_bar">
            <div id="prog_inner"></div>
            </div>  

            <div id="ab_cont">
                <input type="text" name="answerBox" id="answerBox" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" /> 
                <a href="#" id="sub_btn" class="app_btns">Submit</a>
                <div id="icon_div">

                        <div id="icon"></div>
                    <a href="#" id="link">link link link</a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="hid_div">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc bibendum tincidunt magna ut fermentum. 
            </div>

            <div id="btn_cont" unselectable="on">
                    <a href="#" id="btn1" class="app_btns"  unselectable="on">Button 1</a>
                    <a href="#" id="btn2" class="app_btns"  unselectable="on">Button 2</a>
                    <a href="#" id="btn3" class="app_btns"  unselectable="on">Button 3</a>
            </div>

        </div><!--#game_pnl-->






    </div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn1').click(function(){

        $('#hid_div').slideToggle(500);

    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcwkw/) but you can't really see the problem in this because the issue only seems to occur in Opera.

Comment: If you put this into an example that we could view, that'd be great.  Also what version of Opera are you testing on?

Comment: I've put all the scripts into one file so it can just be copied and pasted into a text editor and run in Opera. I've also added a JSfiddle but you can't really see the problem there as the issue seems to only be apparent in Opera. Thanks.